# How to not breaking the referential transparency

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have following code that breaks the referential transparency:

```
val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(system, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)
  .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")

val kafkaProducer1 = producerSettings.createKafkaProducer()
val kafkaProducer2 = producerSettings.createKafkaProducer()

println(kafkaProducer1)
println(kafkaProducer2)
```

The output is:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@49c7b90e
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@10d307f1
```

as you can see, every time when I call the method `createKafkaProducer()`, it produces a new instance of **Kafka Producer**.

How to avoid, that it breaks referential transparency?

Comment: If you make a perfectly functional method that concatenates two strings you will also get two different objects, but that doesn't actually break referential transparency.  Are you sure this does?

Comment: With concatenates two strings, it would not break referential transparency. But what about objects? I am new in scala.

Comment: There's your answer.  the two strings would reside in different addresses and be a different "object". You are seeing the same thing with the two instances of the same thing, but if `kafkaProducer1` doesn't mutate anything and you use it for some task you could use `kafkaProducer2` in its place and get the same result. I assume `KafkaProducer` has a functional interface since I don't know anything about it and the code you have does not imply you are breaking referential transparency any more than concatenating two strings twice. (not including the obvious side effect from `println`)

Comment: @Sylwester When I replace the expressions `producerSettings.createKafkaProducer()` with their corresponding values, well, I fail, because there are different values for the same expression. Doesn't this violate RT?

Comment: It creates every time a new producer. `def createKafkaProducer(): KafkaProducer[K, V] = {
    val javaProps = properties.foldLeft(new java.util.Properties) {
      case (p, (k, v)) => p.put(k, v); p
    }
    new KafkaProducer[K, V](javaProps, keySerializerOpt.orNull, valueSerializerOpt.orNull)
  }`

Comment: @ftor So you made a produceer based on the same arguments and produceerSettings and didn't get a producer that works the same way as the original code?

Comment: @zero_coding It seems thet method is functional so in practise it is the same as `“1 + 1 = ${1 + 1}”`. Doing it twice wil give you two **different** strings with **the same** string value. You agree that that is functional and keeps referential transparency?